# Unequal height for drop-down and textbox

Tags: html, css

I have created a class in css that will beautify the form objects. I observe the height of drop-down and text-box are getting rendered differently, screenshot below along with css and jsfiddle.

[image]

Css

```
    input,select.effect {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    height: 20px;
    padding:3px;
    width:97%;
    font-size:14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

Html

```
<div class="formcontainer">
<form id="bank_details" name="bank_details" action="">
<fieldset><legend>Primary Bank Details</legend>

<div class="bank_name">
<label>Bank Name:</label>
<br />
<select name="" class="effect">
<option value="">Tamilnad Mercantile Co-Operative Bank</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="account_no">
<label>Account No:</label>
<br />
<input type="text" name="" class="effect" id="" />
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fakhruddin/5BdpQ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by setting the [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property, add this to your rule

```
input, select.effect {
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BdpQ/5/)**

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala the docs say IE8 does support box-sizing, plus I just tested it using IE8 browser mode in IE9 and it worked fine

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala It should be woking in IE8 though.

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala using IE8 browser mode I can't load jsfiddle.net at all but I created an external test file and it worked fine

Comment: @Fakhruddin did you test it outside of jsfiddle?

Comment: yes I the code I gave in the jsfiddle was directly from my webpage. Still struggling with it.

Comment: I have one more issue with my code can you please help me out?

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala what's the issue?

Comment: I am currently on mobile will post the code shortly. Actually require some advice over css styling

Answer (score 1):

Separate the two styles:

```
input.effect {
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 height: 27px;
 padding:3px;
 width:97%;
 font-size:14px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
 select.effect {
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 height: 35px;
 padding:3px;
 width:97%;
 font-size:14px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BdpQ/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I separated the styles for the text input, and select tag and removed the height property. It looks fix, although this kind of coding is not advised.

```
 select.effect {
    border:1px solid #ccc;

    padding:3px;
    width:97%;
    font-size:14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
input{
    border:1px solid #ccc;

    padding:3px;
    width:97%;
    font-size:14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

Comment: why would you remove the height? You can separate the styles and keep the height to get the exact result you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same css style for both the classes and make use of inline css by adding height to the select element:

```
<select name="" class="effect" style="height:30px">...
...
```

Hope that solves.

Comment: so you mean to say I need to specify height for both elements differently...it cant be set together.

Comment: you can specify the default height in the css class and specify the changed height in the inline css. Eg: say 25px in the css class which will be the height for input element and if you want different height for select box then put it in the style for select element. You'll be saving on creating two separate classes.

Answer (score 0):

Add some box-sizing to the mix: http://jsfiddle.net/5BdpQ/4/

```
input,select.effect {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    height: 20px;
    padding:3px;
    width:97%;
    font-size:14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala It should be woking in IE8 though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't style default select tag. It's not crossbrowsering. For custom styling select use JQ custom form plugin like this http://vebersol.net/demos/jquery-custom-forms/